# It is necessary to encode labels when using `TfidfVectorizer`, `CountVectorizer` etc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scikit-learn-pipeline

When working with text data, I understand the need to encode text labels into some numeric representation (i.e., by using `LabelEncoder`, `OneHotEncoder` etc.)

However, my question is whether you need to perform this step explicitly when you're using some feature extraction class (i.e. `TfidfVectorizer`, `CountVectorizer` etc.) or whether these will encode the labels under the hood for you?

If you do need to encode the labels separately yourself, are you able to perform this step in a `Pipeline` (such as the one below)

```
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
        ('sgd', SGDClassifier())
    ])
```

Or do you need encode the labels beforehand since the pipeline expects to `fit()` and `transform()` the data (not the labels)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into the `scikit-learn` glossary for the term [transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-transform):

> In a transformer, transforms the input, **usually only X**, into some transformed space (conventionally notated as Xt). Output is an array or sparse matrix of length n_samples and with the number of columns fixed after fitting.

In fact, almost all transformers only transform the features. This holds true for `TfidfVectorizer` and `CountVectorizer` as well. If ever in doubt, you can always check the return type of the transforming function (like the [`fit_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit_transform) method of `CountVectorizer`).

Same goes when you assemble several transformers in a pipeline. It is stated in its [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipelines-and-composite-estimators):

> Transformers are usually combined with classifiers, regressors or other estimators to build a composite estimator. The most common tool is a Pipeline. Pipeline is often used in combination with FeatureUnion which concatenates the output of transformers into a composite feature space. TransformedTargetRegressor deals with transforming the target (i.e. log-transform y). **In contrast, Pipelines only transform the observed data (X)**.

So in conclusion, you typically handle the labels separately and before you fit the estimator/pipeline.